# Add eventlistener for element that was created by javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I write html and javascript:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('#btadd').click(function(e) {
    $('#content').html('<span class="btnmsg"></span>' + $('#result').html());
    $('.btnmsg')[i].click(function(e) {
      alert('span ' + i);
    });
    i++;
  });
});

var i = 0;
```

```html
<input type='button' value='add' id='btnadd'>
<div id='content'></div>
```

On html code, I create a `button` and a `div`. When click on `button`, on `div` will add new element span.

I want that when click on `span`, there will be a alert message. I don't want to use inline js (add `onClick` to `span`), because I write this addon for browser.

So I just want to write this event for `span` in js only.

I write as above code, but nothing to see (no alert message). What can I do?

Comment: Remove the `[i]` from `$('.btnmsg')[i].click(...)` - the way you have it you're trying to call a jQuery method on a DOM element. (Which will lead to your next problem, but at least it's a start...)

Comment: Event delegation is not necessary.

Comment: @guest271314 please elaborate

Comment: @madalinivascu The event can be attached to the element when created using `jQuery(html, attributes)`

Comment: @guest271314 can you provide an example?

Comment: @madalinivascu See Answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just off the top of my head here, this code should do the trick:

```
var i = 0;
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#btnadd').click(function(e) {
       $('#content').html('<span id="btnmsg_' + i + '"></span>'+$('#result').html());
       $('#content').on('click', '#btnmsg_' + i, function(e) {
         alert('span '+i);
       });
     i++;
   });
});
```

Using an ID (ex: #btnmsg_3) will mean you can assign unique event listeners for each created object.

We then use the 'on' function in jQuery to create a dynamic binding instead of one which is dependent on the DOM content.

Does this help?

Comment: _"I believe the best solution would be to write something like this:"_ What do you mean by "best"? Why do you "believe" the same? Note also, no element having `id` `"btadd"` appears at `html` at Question.

Comment: Apologies, I missed the typo by OP. Fixed in my code snippet. By 'best' I simply mean to say this would be the quickest way I could write it.

Comment: What is purpose of `$('body').on('click', '#btnmsg_' + i)`? Why cannot you attach the event directly to `'#btnmsg_' + i` element? Why did you not include _"this would be the quickest way I could write it"_ as description of your estimation of "best" at Answer?

Comment: In some cases when binding an event directly to it's identifier, the dynamic binding will not occur for elements which are generated on the fly. Therefore targeting **body** and then binding the event ensures that the binding can be made as the elements are created. This is just from personal experience

Comment: _"In some cases when binding an event directly to it's identifier, the dynamic binding will not occur for elements which are generated on the fly."_ For the `javascript` at Question? _"Therefore targeting body and then binding the event ensures that the binding can be made as the elements are created."_ Why do you not bind event to parent element `#content`?

Comment: Fair point, I will adjust the question to reflect the #content binding instead - Thanks

Comment: Agreed, it was poor choice of phrasing. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Try event delegation:

```js
  $('#btnadd').click(function(e) {
    $('#content').html('<span class="btnmsg">xxxxxxxxx</span>');
  });

$('#content').on('click','.btnmsg',function(e) {
  alert('span ');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='button' value='add' id="btnadd">
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: What about the number that was in the OP's alert?

Comment: what about it??

Answer (score 0):

Substitute `"btnadd"` for `"btadd"`. Needs more `jQuery()`

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  var i = 0;
  $("#btnadd").click(function(e) {
    $('#content').html(
      $("<span>", {
        "class": "btnmsg",
        html: $("#result").html(),
        on:{"click": function(e) {
                       alert("span " + i);
                     }
           }
      })
     );
    i++;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result">result </div>
<input type='button' value='add' id='btnadd'>
<div id='content'></div>
```

Comment: something new i never seen, from what version is this `on` syntax available ?

Comment: nice and the answer to my question is version 1.8

Comment: this is better than above :)

Comment: @HTCom Not sure what you mean?